# Subclassing a listview for MFC document view

Tags: c++, mfc

I have the following code that creates a list View in my MFC MDI application's document window:

```
int CChildFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CMDIChildWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    CRect getWindowRect, windowRect;
    this->GetWindowRect(&getWindowRect);

    windowRect.left = 0;
    windowRect.top = 0;
    windowRect.right = getWindowRect.right;
    windowRect.bottom = getWindowRect.bottom;

    CListCtrl *CarsListView = new CListCtrl();
    CarsListView->Create( WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LVS_REPORT, windowRect, this, 9001 );

    CarsListView->InsertColumn(0, _T("Reg. no"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 500);
    CarsListView->InsertColumn(1, _T("Status"), LVCFMT_RIGHT, 100);
    CarsListView->InsertColumn(2, _T("Type"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 60);

    CarsListView->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    return 0;
}
```

It works properly, it creates the control and displays it. But I cannot click or hover it. Someone told me that I should subclass this control, but I don't really know what he meant with this. I guess I should create a class `CarsListView` and implement message handlers, but this looks to be very complex. (e.g. Will I have to redesign the hover action on the headings of column?)

I need help on this topic. How can I make it work?

Comment: The rect parameter needs to be a pointer to rect, so this should not compile. Other than that, I don't see anything here that would make clicks not work. Is the whole program dead, or just this control?

Comment: The control is drawn properly. But when I am hovering with the cursor on a heading of a column, it has not reaction. So, yes, I guess the control is dead

Answer (score 4):

In your OnCreate method you initialise a local variable CListCtrl *CarsListView. The variable goes out of scope when the method ends. The control itself will work in this case, but your program will have memory leaks because you do not save the pointer at CarsListView anywhere. I assume you never delete it.

Instead of doing this I recommend you create a member variable of your CChildFrame class, something like this (in the h file):

```
class CChildFrame: public xxxxxx
{
protected:
  CListCtrl CarsListView;
}
```

Then, you have two options:

1. Use [DDE/DDX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0khz1cy9.aspx). You will need to [DDX_Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z04ab59a.aspx) function to subclass the list control. This is the easiest way to do this
2. Follow you method. In your OnCreate method call Create() method to create the window of CarsListView control. You do not need to call `new CListCtrl()`

Having said all that, I think you need familiarise yourself with [Class Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa271536%28v=vs.60%29.aspx). With its help creating member variables and implementing DDE is a matter of a few clicks

Comment: I know about using the Visual Studio class wizard. It is a better method to handle MFC classes.

Comment: I don't have a dialog. I am in the `CChildFrame` class, that as you should know, doesn't have support of any dialogs. So my `Add variable` button in the class wizard is disabled.

Comment: So CarsListView by hand to your CChildFrame class as suggested in this answer.